# How can I stretch a div to 100% page height?

Tags: css, height

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .100PercentHeight{ }
        </style>

        </style>

    <body>
        <div class='100PercentHeight'>hihi</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I stretch div to 100% height of page?

Comment: The sample HTML is not well-formed. "</head>" is missing and "</style>" does not have a corresponding "<style>".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try (it should work in most browsers):

```
.100PercentHeight, html, body {
    height : auto !important; /* Ignored by Internet Explorer, applied everywhere else. */
    height : 100%;            /* Internet Explorer treats as min-height. */
    min-height : 100%;        /* Internet Explorer ignores this. */
}
```

Comment: you'll still need to set a height on <html> and <body> - for IE at least.

Answer (score 6):

Applying

```
html, body, .100PercentHeight{
    height:100%;
}
```

should yield the effect you're looking for. You need it on all three.

However, it often doesn't actually do what you think it might, and can be problematic. Faux-column techniques or "sticky footers" tend to work better.

Comment: I think this is as close as you'll get to a reasonable cross-browser solution.

Comment: Agreed. IExplorer requires the HTML and Body also set, but chrome, and firefox do not

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.100PercentHeight{margin:0; height:100%}

</style>
```

Comment: you have to add the class to your html and body tag also

Comment: I downvoted before you added your first comment. Removed the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You should set 100% height for the body and it should do:

```
body {
...
height:100%;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, as an example.

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; border-style:solid; border-width:5px;">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: I don't remember exact but, this isn't enough i think.

Comment: It seemed alright in IE 8 and Firefox. What would make it not work?

Comment: Just tried it in Safari 3.2.3 and Chrome 2 as well. Seems fine.

Comment: Ah. You wanted it flush against the browser sides, with no white space. Got it. Tweaks are needed in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This way, it will be centered and cover the page if it is longer than one browser view long.

Comment: Two notes: 1) IE 6 does not support opposite dimensions (eg `top` and `bottom`) and will ignore the dimension furthest from the top-left corner. 2) Even in other browsers, this element will still only absolutely fill its parent elements, and strictly speaking both `html` and `body` default to be flexible-height according to the box model (with some display exceptions for backgrounds).

Comment: The above is more likely to work if 'bottom' is used instead of 'botton'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it via JavaScript this code should work for most DOM browsers...

```
<div id="fullDiv" style="border: solid 2px black;">
    Hello example
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var div = document.getElementById('fullDiv');

    div.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight + 'px';

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will not work if you have a DOCTYPE. I'm looking for an answer too, but I have a DOCTYPE.
However, there is a way to do it with a DOCTYPE, but it doesn't work with two divs floating left and right next to eachother, try:

```
(div-name) {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Be aware that this doesn't look good at all when using two divs floating next to eachother. But, it works fine for any other type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest solution that I know of. Unfortunately, however, it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8 and older, as they do not support the vh (viewport height) unit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#full-height{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='full-height'>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```