# How can I make my web page footer in 100% height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I want to stretch the height of my footer to 100% so it stretched its parent footer `div` to the end of the page. I tried this solution but it didn't work for me.

[How can I stretch a div to 100% page height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951712/how-can-i-stretch-a-div-to-100-page-height)

Whenever I tried to set the height of my footer to 100%, it actually show the same size free area on the bottom of the page. I am using 960 Grid system CSS framework. if its not possible in CSS, can we do this in jquery or javascript?. check the demo of my page [DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/23eED/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/23eED/1/) or
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="container_16">
      <div class="grid_16">
         <div class="footer-end-inner">

            <div class="grid_6 alpha copyright">
               <p>Copy right &copy; <b>Mossawir</b></p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid_10 omega footernav">
               <ul class="nav2">
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS code:

```
.footer{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000615;
}

.footer-end-inner{
  background-color: #162e4c;
  height: 80px;
  width: 960px;
}

.footer a{
  color: #98999a;
}

.footer p{
  color: #98999a;
  padding-left:10px;
}

.copyright, .footernav{
 margin-top:30px;
}

.footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that the body is not adding some space:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.footer { margin: 0; }
```

Also ensures the footer is taking up 100%.

Comment: yes its added in my rest.css file.. if i remove it. its actually make some pad around the screen. how to fix this? :(

Comment: @mossawir is the div, `<div class="footer">` contained in another element?

Comment: @pickypg.. no. its in the body tag. their are no parent div .

Answer (score 0):

make sure that its parent has set up fixed width like:

```
<div class="parent" width="300px">
   <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: umm i cannot do that .. because footer div has an stretchable background . i want it to be stretched to 100%.

Comment: are u using jQuery etc on the website?

Comment: @mossawir: as Amber notes the only way that `height: 100%;` will work (in pure html/css) is if the parent element has a specified `height`. If JavaScript is an option it might be possible to adjust the size dynamically, though.

Comment: @amber .. yes i am using jquery but i am applying it on other div elements. not on footer.

Comment: @David Thomas .. can you please tell me how to do it with javascript of jquery?.

Comment: @mossawir: of course, but please edit your question to include the [tag:javascript] or [tag:jquery] tags and also the parent element of the footer-`div`.

Comment: Also, could you put together a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your page, so we can see what you're working with and how the various elements interact?

Comment: hi here you goo.. the code.. i dint include js.. because of lots of file were included
http://jsfiddle.net/23eED/

  i want the footer div to fix when the body hight is lower then the browser screen